# Grub Read Error without USB Connected [13.10]

Tags: boot, grub2

After installing Ubuntu 13.10, I can only load GRUB if I have the LiveUSB I used connected.

What happens is I get a black screen with "Read Error".
To circumvent this error, booting up with the USB connected, GRUB loads up completely fine and off I go. I don't even have to manually boot up the USB.

I have tried two solutions with no luck.

1. `sudo grub-install sda`
2. Automatic `Boot-Repair`

Neither solves my problem.

[Fresh boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6502530/)

Few things to note:

- I've just added a 3TB hard drive recently and reinstalled absolutely everything. However, the problem I am having has existed on my last installation, too. Just saying this in case someone makes the relation and this information helps.
- Ubuntu is on an SSD
- Windows is installed on a my second hard drive, so Grub isn't detecting it. I haven't solved this yet, if you guys notice that in the log.
- While I understand that this may appear to be a duplicate question, no solution they give has been successful. I hope that this changes the fact.

Edit: *It's quite late now. I'll be heading to bed, so I'll respond to any replies whenever I can.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it eventually.

Had to go into BIOS and disable Quick Boot.
Don't have any understanding of why that broke it, but it worked.